# Need to convert python dict in proto message format for gRPC

Tags: python, grpc, proto

I have a format like this and want to convert my python dict to this proto format
proto code:

```
message template{

 message NicSettings{
    string network_adapter = 1;
    string network_name = 2;
 }

 message NetConfig{
    bool keep_mac_address =1;
    bool same_as_source = 2;
   repeated  NicSettings nic_settings = 3;
 }

 NetworkConfig network_config = 3;
```

}

python dict:

```
 template:
  { keepMacAddress: true, 
    sameAsSource : false, 
    nicSettings: [ {networkAdapter: "ethernet0", 
                    networkName: "Calpal1"
                    } ,
                    {networkAdapter: "ethernet1", 
                    networkName: "Calpal2"
                    } 
                 ] 
   }
```

How do I convert this to a proto message to pass it to gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear that your `.proto` is correct (or are there typos in it?) but this looks like it should be something along the lines of

`my_template_message = my_message_module_pb2.template(
    keep_mac_address=my_dictionary['keepMacAddress'],
    same_as_source=my_dictionary['sameAsSource'],
    nic_settings=tuple(
        my_message_module_pb2.template.NicSettings(
            network_adapter=my_subdictionary['networkAdapter'],
            network_name=my_subdictionary['networkName'])
        for my_subdictionary in my_dictionary['nicSettings']
    )
)`

. It's also a little odd in your `.proto` content that you've nested two message definitions inside another message definition - that doesn't look necessary at all.